About single thread async processing when sending fcm messages from java
I wonder if I understand correctly and what you think about FCM.

Each transmission for multicast
Currently, we are sending fcm messages by cutting up to 500 in batches.
Looking at the code, is it correct that asynchronous processing is done in one thread? If asynchronous processing is done in one thread, it seems to send 500 to the code and wait for the response value to arrive before processing it, is it correct?(Blocking)

I think it would be nice to use java21 virtual thread when sending fcm messages. I was wondering what you think.
 public BatchResponse sendEachForMulticast(@NonNull MulticastMessage message) throws FirebaseMessagingException {
 return this.sendEachForMulticast(message, false);

 public BatchResponse sendEachForMulticast(@NonNull MulticastMessage message, boolean dryRun) throws FirebaseMessagingException {
 Preconditions.checkNotNull(message, "multicast message must not be null");
 return this.sendEach(message.getMessageList(), dryRun);}


 public BatchResponse sendEach(@NonNull List<Message> messages, boolean dryRun) throws FirebaseMessagingException {
 return (BatchResponse)this.sendEachOp(messages, dryRun).call();}

 private CallableOperation<BatchResponse, FirebaseMessagingException> sendEachOp(List<Message> messages, final boolean dryRun) {
 final List<Message> immutableMessages = ImmutableList.copyOf(messages);
 Preconditions.checkArgument(!immutableMessages.isEmpty(), "messages list must not be empty");
 Preconditions.checkArgument(immutableMessages.size() <= 500, "messages list must not contain more than 500 elements");
 return new CallableOperation<BatchResponse, FirebaseMessagingException>() {
     protected BatchResponse execute() throws FirebaseMessagingException {
         List<ApiFuture<SendResponse>> list = new ArrayList();
         Iterator var2 = immutableMessages.iterator();

         while(var2.hasNext()) {
             Message message = (Message)var2.next();
             ApiFuture<SendResponse> messageId = FirebaseMessaging.this.sendOpForSendResponse(message, dryRun).callAsync(FirebaseMessaging.this.app);
             list.add(messageId);
         }

         try {
             List<SendResponse> responses = (List)ApiFutures.allAsList(list).get();
             return new BatchResponseImpl(responses);
         } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException var5) {
             throw new FirebaseMessagingException(ErrorCode.CANCELLED, FirebaseMessaging.SERVICE_ID);
         }
     }
 };

}


